# Stored Procedure - Error #1064

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, mysql-error-1064

Getting error during Creating Stored Procedure for Callable Statement: 
I know some thing very simple going wrong, but i'm just unable to figure out!

My QUERY:

USE demo;

```
1. CREATE PROCEDURE
2.  INSERT_emp_data (IN ID INT, IN NAME VARCHAR(2), IN AGE INT, IN IMAGE BLOB)
3. BEGIN
4.  INSERT INTO emp_data VALUES(ID, NAME, AGE, IMAGE);
5. END;
/
```

SQL query:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE
    INSERT_emp_data (IN ID INT, IN NAME VARCHAR(2), IN AGE INT, IN IMAGE BLOB)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO emp_data VALUES(ID, NAME, AGE, IMAGE);
MySQL said: Documentation

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 4
```

Appreciate your help! 
Thank for your time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you write a stored procedure in MySQL, you should use the `DELIMITER` statement.  In addition, you should name your columns so they do not conflict with column names.  And, when using `INSERT` always list the columns name.  So:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE INSERT_emp_data (
    IN IN_ID INT,
    IN IN_NAME VARCHAR(2),
    IN IN_AGE INT,
    IN IN_IMAGE BLOB
)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO emp_data(id, name, age, image)
        VALUES(IN_ID, IN_NAME, IN_AGE, IN_IMAGE);
END;
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Thank You, very much!, I will remember this always from and now, though it was my first time for creating procedure!, Appreciate your help!